# Aptana Studio: Failed to correctly acquire installer error

Tags: node.js, aptana3

I have download Aptana Studio 3.6.1 stand-alone version and attempted to install it. I got an error message stating:

"Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error."

I have now installed node v4.4.5 and it runs but I am still recieving the same error message when I attempt to install Aptana Studio.

Any ideas on what else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Install this: http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows and then run the aptana installer again.

I also recommend not to use Aptana Studio's standalone version since they haven't updated it in a long time & I am not sure about the eclipse plugin either. 
There are many other IDE options out there depending on what you want to work with.
:)

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this but Windows prevents it from installing I have installed eclipse with the pydev extension which is working fine at the moment.